# status bar shows up with a delay in IOS APP Swift

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I would like to hide status bar in launch screen in Swift application, Xcode 8.

Under target property, I set "Status bar is initially hidden" value to "YES" to hide status bar in my launch screen.

Then to make the status bar visible in the app, I programmatically set the "isStatusBarHidden" value to "No" in AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.07, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)

        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false

        return true
    }
```

This code makes my status bar show up in the app, but status bar shows up with a delay. This is the order things happen:

1- Launch screen shows up with no status bar (as intended)

2- The first view shows up with menu and white empty status bar above menu.

3- Status bar with red color, battery and order icons shows up.

I want my status bar shows up before my first view but I don't know how to do it.

*PS, I changed order of lines in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function with no luck.

*PSS, I'm very new with IOS Development.

Here is proof of what I am using!
[image]

Comment: Well, that property changes statusbar color. So I don't think it's wrong. I assume if it didn't have, it would have returned error right?

Comment: No, I'm writing app for IOS8. Does that mean I can't do it? Well, the status bar is not transparent. It has a white background.

Comment: For iOS 8???? Really? That was _years_ ago. What version of Xcode are you _really_ using?

Comment: The status bar hasn't had a background in _years_.